# Reading an XML with SAX, skipping the nodes that passes org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: java, exception, xml-parsing, sax

I am reading a XML using SAX (`javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;`). In that XML, there are some special character like (&,<,>,",') available among the child node values. So, upto that point SAX read the XML successfully, but on that point it throws a `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException`.

For an example, in the below sample XML, SAX reads up to the node value of the  successfully. But it throws this `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException` at the  since the value of *Name* argument has ***<*** in there.

```
<Parent>
   <child1>
      LS-23541723
   </child1>
   <child2 id="2" Name="T-Shirt And Denim - T<D" Rate="500.00">
   </child2>
   <child3>
      <![CDATA[This is the child 2]]>
   </child3>
   <child4>
      <![CDATA[This is the child 4]]>
   </child4>
</Parent>
```

I can't determine the nodes that contains these special characters before hand.(It is dyanamic.) So, What I wanna do is, reading an XML with SAX, ignoring the nodes that contains these like special characters.. Simply, I think I can do this if it is possible to read the XML with SAX, skipping the nodes that pass the org.xml.sax.SAXParseException.

Is this possible and if yes how?

Note : I cannot simply replace them with the Entity Refrences like `&amp;` since, some times the XML nodes are comming with the `&lt;` , `&gt;` as well ( is comming as `&lt;child1&gt;`). So, before starting to read it with SAX, I replace all the Entity References with the Character References.(`replaceAll("&gt;",">"`),etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that SAX can handle this. The XML has to be well-formed. Thus you have to make a bunch of replacements before the text is submitted to SAX. Look for any `'`, `"` or `<` that are not in the right places. `"` between `"`, `'` between `'` and `<` that is not part of a start tag or end tag. That should be feasible. That's the second pass after your first pass that replaces `&lt;` and `&gt;` by their equivalent counterparts.
Ideally you should also watch for comments, CDATA section, etc... to be sure they are well-formed.

Comment: Thanks Ikuty, actually I also have come to that conclusion now.